# How do I run classic ASP with Jet.OLEDB.4.0 in 64bit windows 7?

Tags: asp-classic, oledb

I am getting "ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'" error when I run the following classic ASP code.

```
   Db = "db.mdb"
   ConnStr = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & Server.MapPath(db)
   set conn=server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
   conn.open Connstr
```

So..I googled the error code. The cause is that there is no 64bit Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. I googled for a solution, but I only found how to resolve this error with visual studio.

How do I configure classic ASP in 64bit windows 7 (running IIS 7.5) to run the above code?

Comment: What makes you think there's a way to solve that? Classic ASP is obsolete. Windows 7 (and 64-bit computers in general) is new. That doesn't necessarily mix well.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem in past and it's quite confusing to resolve. Please make sure you have latest version of MDAC installed on the server. It should resolve your issue.