# ABODB.Connection error '800a07a', How to fix this error?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, ms-access-2010

I'm having issues with an ASP page that needs to connect to Access. I am getting the following error message:

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

I have researched and googled the solution but it does not work. I have tried to change the application pool settings to Classic ASP and allow to use 32 bit applications, but when I switch it from 64 bit to 32 bit, the application pool automatically stops and I get an 503 error and the webpage does not show up. If I switch it back to 64 bit I get my original error.

Here is the connection string:

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
conn.open server.mappath("databases/Phone_Directory.mdb")
```

Comment: try finding a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665114/how-do-i-run-classic-asp-with-jet-oledb-4-0-in-64bit-windows-7

Comment: You may also find some useful suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/637326/2144390).

Comment: What IIS version? What OS?

Comment: Also, try creating DSN via ODBC. Not good practice, but it might work.

Comment: I presume that you're running on a 64bit version of Windows? Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416688/architecture-mismatch-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-odbc-drivers

Comment: I believe is 7.0. Thanks so much for everyone's help

Comment: still cant get to work